# Alternativa à banco de dados em PHP?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, array, arquivo

Quero saber se há um jeito de salvar dados de formulários, exibi-los e editá-los sem usar banco de dados? Pois sempre que um software vai fazer integração com banco de dados eu paro pois não entendo muito bem de banco de dados ainda. Estava pensando em fazer com *arrays*, uma posição de cada *array* para um registro, e um array para cada campo do formulário.

Sei que é trabalhoso, mas não queria entrar em banco de dados agora, há outra opção?

Comment: Você pode salvar em arquivos. PHP tem várias funções pra ler e gravar neles. http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_open.asp

Comment: Você está há bastante tempo e já deveria saber que estamos aqui para responder dúvidas específicas, não para passar apostilas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Banco de dados é mais simples do que você imagina. Se não quer instalar um, use o [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php). Ele é usado justamente para não ter que ficar gravando em arquivos. É fundamental que use um recurso assim. Entendo que você esteja querendo aprender aos poucos mas não tem porque evitar isto.

Embora possa parecer simples, gravar em arquivos diretamente pode trazer vários problemas. Eu vou dar uma ideia básica mas ela não leva em conta o funcionamento normal. Você pode achar que é fácil assim, mas não é.

```
$texto = implode(",", $array); //converte o array em um texto simples
$ok = file_put_contents("arquivo.txt", $texto); //grava
$texto = file_get_contents("arquivo.txt"); //lê
$array = explode(",", $texto); //transforma em array novamente
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/FileAsDb.php).

Obviamente que isto é uma enorme simplificação. Se tiver dúvidas específicas vai perguntando.

Comment: Você pode serializar qualquer array com isto: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php